# Google now - retraining the voice model

Tags: google-now, voice-recognition, voice-command, google-voice-actions

Sometimes my phone ignores the Ok Google command. I've noticed that I need to say it in the exact same way, as I said it during the voice model retraining. Even a wrong distance between my mouth and my phone's microphone can cause it to ignore the OK Google command.
Is there a way to save many voice model profiles just like you do it with fingerprints? In android 6.1 you can save up to 5 models of your fingerprint, all of them are checked during the fingerprint authorisation.
If I could record more than 3 "Ok google" commands during the voice model retraining, I think it would work much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sadly not possible.

You could, however, say OK Google a little bit different each time it has to be recorderd. This might help to make sure that your voice is being recognized when you aren't saying OK Google in exactly the same way as your voice model.